# Asp.net application TLS, RC4 cipher error

Tags: asp.net, web, iis

I have deployed a web application on IIS 10 and it was running till yesterday but now it is giving error with IE as.

Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to  again. If this error persists, it is possible that this site uses an unsupported protocol or cipher suite such as RC4 (link for the details), which is not considered secure. Please contact your site administrator

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: RC4 is already abandoned https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4 . Ask your server administrators to harden the ciphers please.

Comment: Are you currently using Internet Explorer 11 (IE11), If yes, please refer to this link: https://theohbrothers.com/posts/fix-internet-explorer-11-error-this-page-cant-be-displayed-turn-on-tls-1-0-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-advanced-settings/